# Add new section to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JavaScript object `customer` that looks like this...

```
Object {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: "26"
}
```

I want to create a `cars` section and add some specifics so it looks like this...

```
Object {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: "26"
    cars:  {
        car1 {
            color: red,
            type: ford
        },
        car2 {
            color: blue,
            type: GMC
        },
        car3 {
            color: white,
            type: toyota
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to do this like this...

```
customer['cars']['car1'] = { color:'white', type:'toyota' }
```

But this gives me the error...

> ```
> customer.cars is undefined
> ```

Where am I going wrong?

​

Comment: create `customer.cars = {}` first and then create inner objects =)

Comment: `customer.cars = { car1: { color: 'white', type: 'toyota' } };`, you need to create the containing object, that will be placed in `customer.cars`. You can do this in two steps as well: `customer.cars = {}; customer['cars']['car1'] = { color:'white', type:'toyota' };`.

Answer (score 4):

#### Problem

The error msg means that `customer.cars` has not been declared/assigned.

---

#### Solution

There are 2 options:

1. *initialize empty `cars` object* (In case that you want to assign each `car`)

```js
var customer = {name:"John Doe",age:"26"};

customer.cars = {}; // init empty cars object
customer.cars.car1 = { color:'white', type:'toyota' }; 
customer.cars.car2 = { color:'blue', type:'GMC' }; 

console.log(customer);
```

2. assign all `cars` property directly.

```js
var customer = {name:"John Doe",age:"26"};
customer.cars = {car1:{color:"red",type:"ford"},car2:{color:"blue",type:"GMC"},car3:{color:"white",type:"toyota"}};

console.log(customer);
```

Comment: Welcome, @jsmitter3 to Stackoverflow. I saw that you forgot to mark the answers as resolved by clicking the tick to help the reader in the future https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

You calling an undefined field `cars` on a `customer` record.

Try to define it first:

```
customer.cars = {}
```

And only then:

```
customer.cars.car1 = {...}
```

You can use `[]` syntax too:

```
customer['cars'] = {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const obj =  {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: "26"
}

obj.cars = {car1 : {color: 'white'}}

console.log(obj)
```

The way you're inserting the object is incorrect. See my example for the correct way to do this.